# 6 screens, 2 different refresh rates, 2 graphic cards

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, refresh-rate, dual-gpu

So, I am aware that with Nvida cards and multiple screens, you sometimes get locked refresh rates that match to the lower of the two.

The way around this is to have the same refresh rate across both screens.

I have three 1440@165 screens and a Wacom Cintiq 1080@60 screen. Because of the Wacom, I often get the locked refresh rate.

My future set up may have seven screens: three basic 1080@60, Wacom Cintiq 1080@60 (so four now), and three 1440@165. The way I plan on getting this many screens is adding a second graphic card.

So my question is, if I connect all the 1080@60 screens on one card and all the 1440@165 screens on the other, would I still get a locking refresh rate or no because it is one refresh rate per GPU?

---

My current GPU is a GTX1080 (not TI). When I do not have my Cintiq connected, I have no issues what so ever on the three 1440@165 screens. When the Cintiq is plugged in, normal productivity works fine with the different refresh rates but things like gaming or some general apps cause the refresh rate drop and lock.

Gsync is on and the GPU is controlling the scale of everything not the display.

I am planning on keeping that GPU and adding a 4090 when they come out.

Thank you for the responses so far :)

Comment: From experience I've used integrated graphics to work around what I suspect is a related issue and yes, it does work to remove any interference or issues. Not an answer because I don't know about 6 screens, only 2.

Comment: The question is going to be if all bandwidth will actually allow you to get 3x 1440@165 over whatever you use. It may not be possible simply because of bandwidth limitations.

Comment: What is your Nvidia GPU model? Being unable to support different refresh rates for every screen at the same time sounds like a very old issue or maybe even misinformation. I don't remember having this issue with cards even as old as GTX 770. Maybe you just need a newer/better GeForce. A single modern GeForce card can do 4 screens with unique display modes and your old one could take care of the other 2 of similar modes if that card actually has the shared refresh rate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue as well, just that it was in 2017/2018 and I tried to find solutions to it to no avail. At the time I had a GTX 1080 GPU as well connected to 1440@165, 1080@144 and 1080@60.

What I found out however was that this is a Windows problem and not Nvidia and is tied to something called DWM (Desktop Window Manager) in Windows.

What I did to semi-solve the problem was switching out my 1080@60 to a 1080@144 same as the other I had, but I think if you have a IGPU (integrated graphics on CPU) I would try to only connect your 60 Hz monitor to that to see if it can help.

Forum post at Microsoft: [Windows locks hz to all monitors if animations](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-locks-hz-to-all-monitors-if-animations/8be79839-ee5e-43fb-84f1-7e6b4a8dfad6)